# Error: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution while running springboot image with mysql image on docker

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

This is the error message, I'm getting while running the spring-boot 3 image with mysql 8 image on docker:

```
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | 2023-09-04T16:33:53.448Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08S01
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | 2023-09-04T16:33:53.449Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Communications link failure
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | 2023-09-04T16:33:53.481Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | 2023-09-04T16:33:53.490Z  WARN 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | 2023-09-04T16:33:53.510Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | 2023-09-04T16:33:53.553Z  INFO 1 --- [           main] .s.b.a.l.ConditionEvaluationReportLogger :
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | 2023-09-04T16:33:53.660Z ERROR 1 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.0.jar!/:3.0.0]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.example.demo.BasicApplication.main(BasicApplication.java:10) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:95) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[spring_rest_docker.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:421) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:352) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    ... 24 common frames omitted
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to open JDBC Connection for DDL execution
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:98) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:109) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:95) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:68) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcConnection(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:63) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.getJdbcDatabaseMetaData(ImprovedExtractionContextImpl.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.processTableResultSet(InformationExtractorJdbcDatabaseMetaDataImpl.java:64) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.getTables(AbstractInformationExtractorImpl.java:564) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.extract.internal.DatabaseInformationImpl.getTablesInformation(DatabaseInformationImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.performTablesMigration(GroupedSchemaMigratorImpl.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.performMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:225) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaMigrator.doMigration(AbstractSchemaMigrator.java:126) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.lambda$process$5(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:143) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:140) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:334) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:66) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:376) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.0.2.jar!/:6.0.2]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    ... 28 common frames omitted
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:828) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:448) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:241) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:198) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource.getConnection(DriverDataSource.java:138) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:359) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:201) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:470) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:561) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:100) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.getConnection(HikariDataSource.java:112) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar!/:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:122) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator$ConnectionProviderJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:284) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.getIsolatedConnection(DdlTransactionIsolatorNonJtaImpl.java:41) ~[hibernate-core-6.1.5.Final.jar!/:6.1.5.Final]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    ... 46 common frames omitted
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:61) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:105) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:151) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.createCommunicationsException(ExceptionFactory.java:167) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.NativeSession.connect(NativeSession.java:120) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:948) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:818) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    ... 59 common frames omitted
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  | Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.pollConnectNow(Net.java:672) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.timedFinishConnect(NioSocketImpl.java:542) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:597) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:327) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:153) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    at com.mysql.cj.protocol.a.NativeSocketConnection.connect(NativeSocketConnection.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-j-8.0.31.jar!/:8.0.31]
springboot-mysql-with-docker-compose-master-api_service-1  |    ... 62 common frames omitted
```

Here is my spring-boot application dependency file.
pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>basic</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>basic</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
       <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- MySQL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>spring_rest_docker</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

These are the database configuration of my spring-boot application
application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/basics?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

Docker file code for configuring application jar
Dockerfile

```
#
# Build stage
#
FROM maven:3.8.3-openjdk-17 AS build
COPY src /home/app/src
COPY pom.xml /home/app
RUN mvn -f /home/app/pom.xml clean package
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/home/app/target/spring_rest_docker.jar"]
```

Docker Compose file
docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - springapimysql-net
    environment:
      - spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://mysqldb:3306/basics?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    
    volumes:
      - .m2:/var/lib/mysql
      
  mysqldb:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    networks:
      - springapimysql-net
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: basics
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
networks:
  springapimysql-net:
```

Comment: Please include the full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: _"Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused"_, you're specifying the wrong host name, or the MySQL server isn't running.

Comment: See [Solving a "communications link failure" with JDBC and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql) and its duplicate.